# c++ excel кодировка

Tags: c++, excel

не понимаю где именно надо указывать кодировку
и почему хардкод он вводит нормально в файл а то что берет из другого файла он вводит как кашу

````
    list <string> lStreet;
    map  <int, double> House;

fout.open("D:\\Начисления_дома.csv");
    fout << "№ строки ; Улица ; № дома ; Начислено;\n";// это вводится правильно

    lStreet.unique();
    int i = 1;
    auto it = lStreet.begin();

    for (auto iter : House)//а вот тут каша
    {
        fout << i           + delimiter;
        fout << *it         + delimiter;
        fout << iter.first  + delimiter;
        fout << iter.second + delimiter + '\n';//выше в коде они заполняются (если надо будет дополню код тут)

        it++;
        i++;
    }
    fout.close();```
````

Answer (score 2):

> Из документации Microsoft Docs https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/fopen-wfopen?view=msvc-170

*fopen* поддерживает файловые потоки Юникода. Чтобы открыть файл Юникода, передайте флаг *ccs=encoding*, задающий нужную кодировку, в *fopen* следующим образом.

`FILE *fp = fopen("newfile.txt", "rt+, ccs=UTF-8");`

**Допустимые значения для ccs кодирования: UNICODE, UTF-8и UTF-16LE.**

То есть в Вашем варианте я так понимаю нужно просто дописать в 4 строке

`fout.open("D:\\Начисления_дома.csv", "rt+, ccs=UTF-8");`

Comment: у open нет такой перегрузки ,а мне надо именно c open делать